# How to brute-force password of a GUI application?

Tags: brute-force

I have forgotten the exact password to a locally installed Windows application I use. There is no password reset function.

What I need is a way to use a source file of the various words/characters and then pass them to the single field in the pop-up window, this should cycle through the various words/characters combinations from the source file.

The password entry window is persistent until the correct password is entered. The password entry window always appears in the same location when the application is active.

If an incorrect password is entered, the field becomes unavailable for data entry for a period of time and then clears to allow entry of new data. There is no password rejected error prompt that requires clicking to clear.

Is there any software that can pass password lists to the app window and if unsuccessful try again?

This is not a UAC secured password prompt - it is generated by the application and uses a unique hash/obfuscation that can not be directly targeted.

Comment: This sounds very specific so I'm not sure there will be off the shelf software that does specifically what you want. Reading your source file and concatenating the words as you describe is not difficult programatically speaking. Then it is just a matter of moving the cursor to the correct position and simulating key strokes. I don't know what your knowledge of programming is and whether you could write something like this yourself, but like I said it does specific to your application so I doubt there is an off the shelf solution (but I would be glad to be wrong).

Comment: exactly what i did and after about 4 days it was found - what the forum seems to not understand is that this is a totally standalone application - it has no authentication linkages to the OS - its all built into the app.